# Is it legal to publish a Noughts and crosses (tic-tac-toe) game?

Tags: legal

Is it be legal to publish a Noughts and crosses game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search online indicates that Noughts and crosses is a several thousands years old, so it doesn't have any copyright.

I'd just like to point out if you plan to make such a game for practise, and not to publish it, you don't have to worry about copyrights or patents. If you want to publish it and earn money, I guess you know that there's plenty of noughts and crosses in the market already.

Answer (score 0):

This is not legal advice.

**You can copy:**

- Mechanics

**You cannot copy:**

- Art, sounds
- Lore/transcripts
- Other in-game content

Comment: Even the mechanics item is fuzzy. See the case of Triple Town & Yeti Town. The clone used the same mechanics but all its own art & assets and still got in trouble for it.

Comment: @DMGregory interesting! I've just read up on it and to me it seems that they've copied a tad more than just mechanics. Their object hierarchies were copied too and to me that sounds like content.